# Angular is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angular js not working in my browser even after a proper code

my code
`

```
  <body ng-app>

  <div ng-controller="MainController">

    <h4>{{val}}</h4>

  </div>


<script>

var MainController = function($scope){
    $scope.val = "Testing angular";
};


</script>
`
```

The error showing in my browser is :
`angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate your **module** first:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController);

MainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MainController($scope){
    $scope.val = "Testing angular";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <h4 ng-bind="val"></h4>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3

Angular stopped looking for controllers on the window object starting from 1.3:

**Doesn't Work:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>

  <div ng-controller="MainController">

    <h4>{{val}}</h4>

  </div>


<script>

var MainController = function($scope){
    $scope.val = "Testing angular";
};


</script>
```

**Works:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>

  <div ng-controller="MainController">

    <h4>{{val}}</h4>

  </div>


<script>

var MainController = function($scope){
    $scope.val = "Testing angular";
};


</script>
```

Comment: It works now.. but i don't want to use the online code so what i have to do for that..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Angular that it needs to use the controller that you are creating. You do that by explicitly telling it using:

```
angular.module('module-name',[/*any dependencies*/]).controller('controller-name', controllerFunction)
```

Here's an example that you can just embed and run ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/moheyuw/edit?html,js,output)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <h4>{{val}}</h4>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var MainController = function($scope){
    $scope.val = "Testing Angular";
  };

  angular.module("TestApp",[])
  .controller("MainController", MainController);

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```